# php / Javascript / Ajax loading content does not work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to load content from a php file which name is "include.php" to a  in another php file which name is "index.php". But the loading does not work. The code is as below:

The file: index.php

```
<header>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function load(){
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechage = function (){
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById(adiv).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
       }

        xmlhttp.open('GET', 'include.php', true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="load();">
    <div id="adiv"></div>
</body>
```

The File: include.php

```
<?php
    echo 'Hello!';
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Go to Inspect element -> network tab -> what can you see there?

Comment: There is a list of my three files: "index.php", "style.css", and"include.inc.php".  Method of all these three files is "GET". STATUS for "index.php" and "include.inc.php" is "OK". STATUS of "style.css" is "Not Modified."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should it not be `document.getElementById("adiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;`? Notice the quotes.

Comment: Thanks, and I correct this error, but still does not work.

Comment: It works now. I changed `xmlhttp.onReadyStateChange = function (){` back to `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` & corrected `getElementById("adiv")`. Thanks all of your helps. @Nitesh Kumar Anand, @Kirs Sudh, @Michael Christensen, @ Kunal Pradhan

Answer (score 1):

If what you are doing is the way you describe then this is simpler:

```
<header>
<?php include("include.php") ?>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="load();">
    <div id="adiv"></div>
</body>
```

If you want to get result from `include.php` into JavaScript then you'll probably be better using ajax.

By the way, if you are planning a "universal header" for all your PHP files, you don't need to echo it just write it as normal HTML with any necessary PHP tags

Comment: Hey if you like the answer can you give a check mark to signify this question has been answered?

Comment: Thanks Michael. What I want to do is loading some content from another file to a div without refresh the page. In this case, when I click the "Submit" button, the content on another file should be loaded under the "Submit" button but no page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

`....xmlhttp.onreadystatechage = function (){
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.st...`

Check the spelling `onReadyStateChange`.